# how can i add something to a dictionary in python which is present in another file from another python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to get contacts in form of a python dictionary, this dictionary is present in the file named 'phone.py', and I want to add a contact to this dictionary from another function which is in another file named 'test.py'.

phone.py

```
phone_numbers={
'john': '+91123456789',
'berry': '+91987654321',
}
```

test.py

```
import phone.py

def add_contact():

    name_contact = input("what is the name :")
    phone_contact = input("contact number")
    file = open("phone.py", "a", encoding='utf-8')
    file.truncate()
    file.write("'"+name_contact+"'" + ':'+"'+91"+phone_contact+"'"+",")
    file.close()
add_contact()
```

what I am currently getting as result.

phone.py

```
phone_numbers={
'john': '+91123456789',
'berry': '+91987654321',
}'jerry': '+916543217890',
```

what I want it to be.

phone.py

```
phone_numbers={
'john': '+91123456789',
'berry': '+91987654321',
'jerry': '+916543217890',
}
```

Comment: Are you importing your `phone.py` into other python code as a variable? If not, would a json file suit your needs? If you switch to json, there are more efficient ways of handling the updates.

Comment: i have imported phone.py in test.py and want to add new contacts to it. i don't know JSON yet.

Comment: it's bad practice to name your data file as python script. just a `phones.json` file is better.

Comment: ok, thanks, I will try it  :)

Answer (score 0):

Your file has textual content.
You can use the following method add lines to your file

```
def add_contact():
    name_contact, phone_contact = read_param()
    lines = None
    with open('phone.py') as input_file:
        lines = input_file.readlines()
        lines[-1:] = "'{0}':'+91{1}',{2}".format(name_contact, phone_contact, '\r')
        lines.append("}")
    with open("phone.py", 'w') as output_file:
        output_file.writelines(lines)
        output_file.close()

def read_param():
    name_contact = input("what is the name :")
    phone_contact = input("contact number :")
    return name_contact, phone_contact
```

But it is better to keep the data in json format or even simpler (not in the form of dict but one contact in each line)

for example

1. simple records like this
   "john": "+91123456789"
   "berry": "+91987654321"
   .
   .
   .

and just append new line

```
def append_line():
    with open('phone.py', 'a') as input_file:
        name_contact, phone_contact = read_param()
        input_file.writelines("'{0}':'+91{1}'".format(name_contact, phone_contact))
```

2. json

your file contents be like this

```
{
"john": "+91123456789",
"berry": "+91987654321"
}
```

and use the following code

```
def add_contact_json():
    with open('phone.py') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        name_contact, phone_contact = read_param()
        data[name_contact] = "'+91{0}".format(phone_contact)

    with open('phone.py', 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(data, json_file)
```